# How can we have two Gmail accounts open on an iPad?

Tags: gmail, ipad

I love the Gmail iPad web interface, but my girlfriend loves it too.

How could we both use Gmail on the iPad without having to login/logout all the time to switch accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers. iCab or Atomic. Then just agree keep one browser for you and another for your girlfriend.

Comment: How do I download a second browser?

Comment: From the App Store. Just search for `iCab`, `Chrome`, `Coast` or `Atomic`, and download the one that seems best.

Answer (score -1):

You can both login to the same browser, then instead of logging out completely you can just switch accounts. Should be easy enough.

Comment: How? Remember, the question was originally about an iPad.